# Build Error for Spring MVC Application

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, build

I'm fairly new to the Spring framework. I have recently installed SpringSource Tool Suite (version 2.8.1.RELEASE). Using Subclipse, I have checked out a Spring MVC project that my team mate has created. It works fine on his machine, but we can't figure out why a build error is happening on my machine.

I use Tomcat v6.0 Server to run the project. This is part of the error:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
2012-jan-30 13:43:46 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:926)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:297)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
```

The Tomcat server has the following classpath: Bootstrap entries: JRSE System Library [jdk1.6.0_27], spring-2.5.2-20080220-410.jar. User entries: bootstrap.jar, tools.jar

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to your build path settings and make sure you have Apache Tomcat library included.

Right-click your project name from Project Explorer, click properties. In the properties dialog box, click Java Build Path from the list on left, then open libraries tab. Confirm if Apache Tomcat library is there.

If it is not there, click Add Library -> Server Runtime -> Apache Tomcat v x.0 -> Finish.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Yes, I had no reference to the Apache Tomcat library in the Build Path (strange since I checked the working code out of Subclipse). Nevertheless, the problem persists (the error message seems to be exactly the same) despite this addition. :-(

Comment: You might also be missing "Web App Libraries" in your build path. If it is not there (same place), click Add Library -> Web App Libraries -> Next -> Choose your project from the list -> Finish.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that library as well. However, the problem persists. Trying to assist, my team mate just made a fresh STS installation and got the same problem. He created a MVC test project; didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I finally got rid of this excruciating problem by right-clicking project name -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export. I checked JRE System Library and Maven Dependencies.

Another problem was that `pom.xml` referenced `spring-core` twice. I removed both and added this manually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also, check that Project -> Build Automatically is enabled. Otherwise classes may not be copied to the Tomcat server.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem moving the Tomcat folder to C: and then reinstalling the server in eclipse. It was a permission issue because it was in my desktop folder before.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following version of Spring web...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```