# Error configuring application listener spring tomcat

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have trouble to run my web application
I  thought use:

```
-hibernate 3 width hbm
-spring 2.5
-Servlet and jsp for web
```

With jboss works without problems.
With tomcat error:

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax / servlet / ServletContextListener
```

I also added in the classpath in "open launch configuration" of the tomcat jar.

Comment: How are you running your application? Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064337/build-error-for-spring-mvc-application

Comment: thanks to the following link I solved the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Error for Spring MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064337/build-error-for-spring-mvc-application)